# Python - Inserting special characters into JSON string to print them on bash terminal

Tags: python, json, special-characters

I am constructing JSON dictionary with some special characters to print words in bold and various colors on the bash terminal like this:

```
# 'field' is a part of a bigger JSON document 'data'
field["value"] = '\033[1m' + string_to_print_in_bold + '\033[0m'
```

Later on, I'm calling `dumps` to create and print out my JSON:

```
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False))
```

However, on the terminal I see this:

> "value": "\u001b[1mstring_to_print_in_bold\u001b[0m"

instead of

> "value": "**string_to_print_in_bold**"

Note that **ensure_ascii=False**!

What am I missing?

Comment: What happens if you print(field[“value”])

Comment: Which terminal you are using?

Comment: Your expectations are off; JSON is a data serialization format, not something which should be interpreted when displayed.

Comment: print(field[“value”]) works as expected

Comment: Normally adding `ensure_ascii` will [result the `\u` notation not be included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865180/unicode-values-in-strings-are-escaped-when-dumping-to-json-in-python), the affected characters are not unicode but are control characters, and the [JSON specification requires them to be escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23112193/escaping-of-json-control-characters-within-string).  So no, you can't do what you wanted to do, as your goal results in an invalid JSON document.

Comment: You are probably looking for [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26459749/pretty-printing-json-with-ascii-color-in-python) involving a terminal formatter.  Again, [the specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47607810/control-characters-in-json-string) prohibits JSON from including those control characters unescaped.

Answer (score 3):

From a design perspective, you should separate formatting from your data.
If you only want to pretty-print json with color, `pygments` provides a terminal text formatter to prettify your json output:

```
import json
from pygments import highlight
from pygments.lexers import JsonLexer
from pygments.formatters import TerminalFormatter

data = {"value": "myvalue"}
json_str = json.dumps(json_object, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
print(highlight(json_str, JsonLexer(), TerminalFormatter()))
```